# Stripping out \\n plus whitespace using .strip() and regex is not working

Tags: python, regex, newline, strip

I've been attempting to strip out the \n plus the whitespace before and after the words from a string, but it is not working for some reason.

This is what I tried:

```
.strip(my_string)
```

and

```
re.sub('\n', '', my string)
```

I have tried using `.strip` and `re` in order to get it working, but it simply returns the same string.

#### Example input:

```
\\n                    The people who steal our cards already know all of this...\\n
          \\n                    , \\n                    I\'m sure every fraud minded person in America is taking notes.\\n
            \\n
```

#### Expected output would be:

```
The people who steal our cards already know all of this..., I\'m sure every fraud minded person in America is taking notes.
```

Comment: you'll need to show your code

Comment: Are you trying to strip out an actual newline `\n`, or the `\ ` character followed by the `n` character?

Comment: Please include your own attempt, and tell us *how* it is not working. Include any error messages you get.

Comment: I actually didn't know that there was a character there

Comment: And also add the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', x)
```

A usage example follows:

```
In [10]: x
Out[10]: 'hello \n world   \n blue'

In [11]: re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', x)
Out[11]: 'hello world blue'
```

If you'd also like to grab the sequence of characters `r'\n'`, then let's grab them as well:

```
 re.sub(r'(\s|\\n)+', r' ', x)
```

And the output:

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 'hello \\n world  \n  \\n blue'

In [15]: re.sub(r'(\s|\\n)+', r' ', x)
Out[15]: 'hello world blue'
```

Comment: That almost works, in that it removes the white space, but the \\n is still there.

Comment: `\\n The people who steal our cards already know all of this...\\n \\n , \\n I\'m sure every fraud
 minded person in America is taking notes.` is what I'm getting

Comment: Note that `'\\n'` is a string of two characters (a backslash and a n) while `'\n'` is a single character (a newline character). That being said, I've edited my answer.